# Convert string to int, float or leave it as string, depending on the best option

Tags: python, string, floating-point, integer

I'm trying to handle a dataset containing only `str`, but the values of the `str` can be either real text or something like `"1.0"` and `"3.54"`.

I want to convert all string to the best possible type, which means `1.0` should be converted to `int`, `3.54` should be converted to `float` and everything else should stay `str`.

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: The string `"1.0"` is clearly meant to represent a floating point number (even though one with an integer value) - why would you not want to convert it to float?

Answer (score 3):

lets try

```
def convert(txt):
try:
    k = float(txt)
    if k%1 ==0:
        return int(k)
    return k

except ValueError:
    return txt
```

now what I'm thinking is, the input is either a number or not,
anyway we can float it. if it is also divisable by 1 its an int and we're done. if it isn't then it is a float after all and we're done.
any other case: there's nothing that we can do, and then let's return it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try except` block to perform the operation.

```
for s in string:
    try:
        //convert to int or float
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: I don't think your answer addresses exactly what is being asked. You should convert to `int` or `float` but those specifics is what the user is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
strings = ["some weird junk", "1.0", "2.345", -1000]

for string in strings:
    try:
        number, decimal = string.split(".")
        try:
            if decimal == "0":
                value = int(number)
            else:
                value = float(string)
        except:
            value = string
    except (ValueError, AttributeError):
        try:
            value = int(string)
        except ValueError:
            value = string

    print(value, type(value))
```

Which yields

```
some weird junk <class 'str'>
1 <class 'int'>
2.345 <class 'float'>
-1000 <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def convert(string):
    possible = [str, int, float]
    for func in possible:
        try:
            result = func(string)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if str(result) == string and type(result) is not str:
            return result
    return string

strings = ['hello', '1', '1.0', '1.9']
for string in strings:
   result = convert(string)
   print(type(result), result)
```

```
Output:
<class 'str'> hello
<class 'int'> 1
<class 'float'> 1.0
<class 'float'> 1.9
```